# calling sibling component function with Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Before using the router, I was able to click Done from the NewContactPage which calls the add function in the ContactsPage to add a new person in the list

```
  <div>
    <ContactsPage ref={instance => { this.contacts = instance; }} />
    <NewContactPage handleSubmit={e => this.contacts.add(e) } />
  </div>
```

With the router, I am not sure how the communication could work,

```
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/" component={ContactsPage} />
      <Route path="/add" component={NewContactPage} />
    </div>
  </Router>
```

source code: https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-architecture-xww2c

Many thanks!

Comment: Redux can help with this by having a central place where all states and actions can be in

Comment: typically this would submit the new Person to an endpoint. This will add the person to the people.json data (or database) then return to the list.